# How does HTML5 input type email works without top level domain name

Tags: html

The input type =  email tag in html5 works even if the top level domain name is not present

```
<form action = "yourPage" method = "get">
    <input type =  'email' name ="emailName" >
    <input type = 'submit'>
</form>
```

for eg: if we type

```
foo@bar
```

instead of

```
foo@bar.com
```

The form will be submitted. Can anyone explain why it behaves like this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71173721/3597276

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because `bar` is a valid hostname, which makes `foo@bar` a valid email address.

Chrome is not going to check for you whether the address or host are *actually in use*, only whether the semantics are correct.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Domain_part for examples of valid email addresses.

Comment: easiest example: `root@localhost` is actually an extremely common address  :)