# Jersey Bean validation other than hibernate-validator

Tags: java, validation, jersey-2.0

When i Try to validate email id using jersey the built in hibernate-validator is not validating it properly the fallowing string ***lafalsdf@ga*** get evaluatied to valid and it fallows JSR 303 which is old .I need library which validates according to JSR 311 & JSR 339 . Or any other library which is better than hibernate-validator

If there is any library please suggest me . I have done research and was not able to find any.

And also give me code to configure it in jersey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, an emailId like **lafalsdf@ga** is valid as per RFC 822 ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373433/how-does-html5-input-type-email-works-without-top-level-domain-name)) because `ga` is a valid local host name. Since most of the email validators follow RFC 822, they too consider it valid. This is the case for Hibernate Validator,Java's native `InternetAddress.validate()` etc. However there is [Apache Commons Validator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator) project which provides an option to ignore local addresses when performing a validation.

If your concern is only with email validation, you don't have to look for a replacement for Hibernate Validator. You can write a custom annotation and validator which uses Apache commons validator as shown below.

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = CommonsEmailValidator.class)
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface CommonsEmail {
String message() default "{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email.message}";

Class<?>[] groups() default {};

Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

/**
 * Defines several {@code @Email} annotations on the same element.
 */
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface List {
    CommonsEmail[] value();
}

public static class CommonsEmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CommonsEmail, CharSequence> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(CommonsEmail annotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(CharSequence value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return EmailValidator.getInstance(false).isValid(value.toString());
    }

  }
}
```

Now, you can use new `@CommonsEmail` instead of `@Email`. `EmailValidator` is part of commons validator library. So make sure commons-validator.jar is in your classpath.