# inconsistent email format of html input field with laravel email validation

Tags: html, laravel, email-validation, email-formats

In my blade file i have a html form for user in which input field email have type email.   But i think it provide inconsistent email format validation. example it show abc@xyz and abc@xyz.com both are correct email address but in my controller, validator method return me invalid email format for abc@xyz.   How can i resolve this issue???

In my blade file:

```html
<input type="email" name="email" value="">
```

And in my controller:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'email'       => 'email|unique:table_name,col_name',
    ],[
     'email.unique' => 'email is already in used',
   ]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->all())->withErrors($validator);
  }
```

Comment: I guess `abc@xyz` isn't valid. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Comment: yes, abc@xyz isn't valid email address, but html input field type="email" accept it as valid email address format

Comment: That's [ok (see email paragrapgh)](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp). You see that `user@localserver` is till valid, according to wiki. You can add your own front-end validation with jQuery.

Comment: can you provide that jQuery code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually Laravel using `PHP` builtin function called `filter_var` ([source code](https://github.com/illuminate/validation/blob/master/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L659)).

```
// Illuminate\Validation\Concerns\ValidateAttributes

/**
 * Validate that an attribute is a valid e-mail address.
 *
 * @param  string  $attribute
 * @param  mixed   $value
 * @return bool
 */
public function validateEmail($attribute, $value)
{
    return filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false;
}
```

The rules implemented by `PHP` is quite different with the rules implemented by the browser. `abc@xyz` passed the browser validation rule because `xyz` is a valid `hostname` (you can read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373433/how-does-html5-input-type-email-works-without-top-level-domain-name)). But `PHP` implementing more strict rule that the email address should contains top level domain.

Comment: Thank you saputra for your answer